# correct wrong dates for an external disk

Tags: macos, external-disk

This is my external disk with 2 volumes: 1 for Time Machine, the rest for external disk. I don't understand the reason for these wrong dates and what caused it or how I can correct them. Is there a way to correct this? Any help is appreciated.

[image: Mac OS Monterey 12.4]

Comment: I don't think Time Machine works on exFat. exFat also does not have all the metadata other file systems have so definitely I would expect one the creation date of beginning Unix time and the modification of begining DOS time (ie exFATS native OS) is to be expected. So I think you need to reformat as an Apple filesystem

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your Time Machine volume is not using ExFAT… or it just wouldn't work. ExFAT cannot hold many data types needed by macOS - including extended attributes, access control lists or even basic file permissions -  & should not be used unless portability between Mac & Windows/nix is paramount.

ExFAT is also not a journaled file system, so in the event of a disconnect at write, the entire volume could be lost.

Personally, if you need cross-platform compatibility, I would format it HFS+ & install something like [Paragon HFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) on any Windows machines that also need to physically access the drive.

Drive manufacturers tend to ship drives ready-formatted as MBR/ExFAT because it "works" on most computers straight out of the box, but it's not the best format for any computer, just the most portable. First thing you should do with any new drive is format it GUID/HFS+ for HDD or GUID/APFS for SSD.

btw, the dates you see are a mis-reading or mis-interpretation. There are no valid dates that the Mac can read, so 'beginning of epoch' dates are substituted.
They can, amusingly, be misinterpreted further, depending on time zone & daylight saving…

[image]